# Getting unable to create a new remote session, using Appium, browserstack, proxies and okhttp, Java, Eclipse

Tags: java, proxy, okhttp, browserstack

I'm very new to automation and I'm trying to write a code in Java to setup remote connection using proxy and okhttp. But, it keeps throwing error:
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: Too many tunnel connections attempted: 21

Getting the error on the last line of the code snippet, i.e. on the return statement.
Request your help in finding the issue in my code. Below is my code snippet:

**Function is being called as below:**

```
 General.driver = connectViaProxy(caps);
```

**Implementation of connectViaProxy:**

```
public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> connectViaProxy(DesiredCapabilities caps) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    
    String proxyHost = Config.getValue("proxy.host");
    int proxyPort = Config.getValueint("proxy.port");
    String proxyUserDomain = Config.getValue("proxy.user-domain");
    String proxyUser = Config.getValue("proxy.user");
    String proxyPassword=EncryptionUtil.passwordDecoder(Config.getValue("proxy.encrypted-password").getBytes());

 URL url;

    try {
        url = new URL("https://"+Config.getValue("BrowserStack.userName")+":"+Config.getValue("BrowserStack.accessKey")+"@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

 Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator()
 {
        @Override

        public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic(proxyUserDomain + "\\" + proxyUser, proxyPassword);
        return response.request().newBuilder()
        .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
        .build();
        }
        };
         
    okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
    .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator);
    
    Factory factory = new MyHttpClientFactory(new org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient(client.build(), url));
    HttpCommandExecutor executor = new AppiumCommandExecutor(MobileCommand.commandRepository, url, factory);
    return new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(executor, caps);
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proxy in your network is not passing the first request made by your test script to establish connection to BrowserStack.

Try to whitelist *.browserstack.com in your proxy for ports 80 and 443.

If that does not work, use local testing and follow the steps from the below documentation so that the request to BrowserStack is by-passed by the proxy.

https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/test-behind-proxy/configure-settings

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for your quick answer. I tried with the BrowserstackLocal & found that authentication issue was that I was passing domain with username in line:
String credential = Credentials.basic(proxyUserDomain + "\\" + proxyUser, proxyPassword);

New coded line is:
String credential = Credentials.basic(proxyUser, proxyPassword);

Now, I'm getting the below error. Any idea on this please:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: Too many tunnel connections attempted: 21

Comment: Can someone please help me with this.. I'm still without any clue :(